# Не обновляется БД в андроид приложении

Tags: android, android-sqlite

Приложение андроид с поиском по готовой бд.
После обновления данных в бд меняю версию с 1 на 2, но в приложении база сразу не обновляется, а обновляется только после того как в настройках телефона очистить данные приложения(те заходим в настройки выбираем наше приложение и там стираем данные), после этого приложение запускается с обновленной бд. Что не так в коде?

activity_main.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <EditText android:id="@+id/userFilter"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Поиск" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/userList"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

MainActivity.java:

```
 package com.energo.myapplication;
    import android.database.Cursor;
    import android.database.SQLException;
    import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.text.Editable;
    import android.text.TextWatcher;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.widget.FilterQueryProvider;
    import android.widget.ListView;
    import android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    DatabaseHelper sqlHelper;
    SQLiteDatabase db;
        Cursor userCursor;
        SimpleCursorAdapter userAdapter;
        ListView userList;
        EditText userFilter;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            userList = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.userList);
            userFilter = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.userFilter);
            sqlHelper = new DatabaseHelper(getApplicationContext());
            // создаем базу данных
            sqlHelper.create_db();
        }
        @Override
        public void onResume() {
            super.onResume();
            try {
                db = sqlHelper.open();
                userCursor = db.rawQuery("select * from " + 
    DatabaseHelper.TABLE, null);
                String[] headers = new String[]{DatabaseHelper.COLUMN_QUES, 
    DatabaseHelper.COLUMN_ANSW};
                userAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, 
    android.R.layout.two_line_list_item,
                        userCursor, headers, new int[]{android.R.id.text1, 
    android.R.id.text2}, 0);

                // если в текстовом поле есть текст, выполняем фильтрацию
                // данная проверка нужна при переходе от одной ориентации экрана 
    к другой
                if(!userFilter.getText().toString().isEmpty())

    userAdapter.getFilter().filter(userFilter.getText().toString());

                // установка слушателя изменения текста
                userFilter.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

                    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) { }

                    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int 
    count, int after) { }
                    // при изменении текста выполняем фильтрацию
                    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int 
    before, int count) {

                        userAdapter.getFilter().filter(s.toString());
                    }
                });

                // устанавливаем провайдер фильтрации
                userAdapter.setFilterQueryProvider(new FilterQueryProvider() {
                    @Override
                    public Cursor runQuery(CharSequence constraint) {

                        if (constraint == null || constraint.length() == 0) {

                            return db.rawQuery("select * from " + 
    DatabaseHelper.TABLE, null);
                        }
                        else {
                            return db.rawQuery("select * from " + 
    DatabaseHelper.TABLE + " where " +
                                    DatabaseHelper.COLUMN_QUES + " like ?", new 
    String[]{"%" + constraint.toString() + "%"});
                        }
                    }
                });

                userList.setAdapter(userAdapter);
            }
            catch (SQLException ex){}
        }
        @Override
        public void onDestroy(){
            super.onDestroy();
            // Закрываем подключение и курсор
            db.close();
            userCursor.close();
        }
    }
```

DataBaseHelper.java:

```
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.content.Context;
import android.util.Log;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;

class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
private static String DB_PATH; // полный путь к базе данных
private static String DB_NAME = "questions.db";
private static final int SCHEMA = 2; // версия базы данных
static final String TABLE = "otvet"; // название таблицы в бд

// названия столбцов
static final String COLUMN_ID = "_id";
static final String COLUMN_QUES = "questions";
static final String COLUMN_ANSW = "answers";


private final Context myContext;

DatabaseHelper(Context context) {

    super(context, DB_NAME, null, SCHEMA);
    this.myContext=context;
    DB_PATH =context.getFilesDir().getPath() + DB_NAME;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
}
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion,  int newVersion) {

}

void create_db(){
    InputStream myInput = null;
    OutputStream myOutput = null;
    try {
        File file = new File(DB_PATH);
        if (!file.exists()) {
            this.getReadableDatabase();
            //получаем локальную бд как поток
            myInput = myContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);
            // Путь к новой бд
            String outFileName = DB_PATH;

            // Открываем пустую бд
            myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

            // побайтово копируем данные
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int length;
            while ((length = myInput.read(buffer)) > 0)
                myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);


            myOutput.flush();
            myOutput.close();
            myInput.close();
        }
    }
    catch(IOException ex){
        Log.d("DatabaseHelper", ex.getMessage());
    }
}
SQLiteDatabase open()throws SQLException {

    return SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(DB_PATH, null, 
SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

При увеличении версии БД само обновление происходить не будет. Произойдет вызов метода `onUpgrade()` класса-наследника `SQLiteOpenHelper` где вы должны самостоятельно произвести действия для обновления БД. В вашем случае (копирование из assets/), видимо, текущюю БД нужно удалить, тогда будет записана новая база (копирование из assets/ происходит, когда в каталоге пользователя нет никакой базы)