# Изменение размера шрифта в listview

Tags: java, android, listview, button

Есть приложение с таблицей [Не обновляется БД в андроид приложении](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/802529), необходимо по нажатию кнопки менять размер шрифта. В `activity_main.xml` создал кнопку, в ней прописал `android:onClick="Click"`. В `MainActivity.java` прописал

```
public void Click(View view) {
    EditText bigTextView = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.userFilter);
    bigTextView.setTextSize(40);
}
```

Это для EditText где строка поиска с текстом Поиск, но если подставлять `ListView`, ничего не работает, `setTextSize` подчеркивает красным и пишет `Cannot resolve method setTextSize(java.lang.string)`

Comment: Причем тут `ListView`?

Comment: Я использую готовую базу данных с текстом, она размещена в ListView, размер текста, который находится в ListView необходимо увеличивать или уменьшать по нажатию кнопки button. В activity_main.xml расположены два элемента EditText (там строка куда вводить текст для поиска по бд, в нем могу изменять шрифт, цвет, тест) и ListView (здесь таблица из бд, в ней не получается изменять), т.е. если написать так:`public void Click(View view) {
ListView bigTextView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.userList);
bigTextView.setTextSize(40);
}` то выдаст ошибку.